# jenkinsfile checkout git tag

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying git checkout in `Jenkinsfile` following way

```
stage ('Repo Checkout') {
    steps {
        dir('My-Repo') {
            git branch: '${BUILD_BRANCH}',
                credentialsId: 'jenkins',
                url: 'git@github.com:my-org/my-repo.git'
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to checkout specific tag in `Jenkinsfile` ?

Comment: You might not be able to do it with the git step.  Try using the snippet generator for general SCM, select git and it probably gives you a way to checkout a tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this.

```
 stage('CheckOut code from git tag') {
      checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "refs/tags/v3.0"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: false, recursiveSubmodules: false, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "gitlab-ssh-user", url: "git@192.168.44.132:xxxx/xxxxx.git"]]])
 }
```

Here I am checking out tag `v3.0` and in case you want to checkout any branch just mention `*/branch_name`

NOTE: This will work in both scripted and declarative pipeline.

Comment: how to checkout the latest tag instead of hardcoding?

Answer (score 5):

You can speed it up by doing a shallow clone

```
stage ('Checkout') {
  checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/v3.0']],
    extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', shallow: false, depth: 0, reference: '']],
    userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs,
  ])
}
```